# TTFB from very high to very low Cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, caching, cloudflare

We are using a wordpress setup with hosting on Google Cloud and Cloudflare.
In Cloudflare we are using the page cache feature which should help to decrease the TTFB substantially. What it basically does is to cache every static page and serves it to the client directly. What makes me wonder is that if I make a request in the morning the TTFB is like over 1 second. All requests after that the TTFB reduces to 70ms. That is a lot. It almost feels like a browser cache when I visit a website for the second time. But after some time the TTFB spikes again to over 1 second, almost as if Cloudflare drops the cache. That's why we additionally added the EDGE Cache TTL Time of 1 month, but still. I have those daily spikes and I think every user has a TTFB over 1 second when visiting our site for the first time.

Any guesses why this is so random?

This is the guide directly from cloudflare about the page cache:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/236166048-Caching-Static-HTML-with-WordPress-WooCommerce

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe Cloudflare doesn't cache universally, meaning that one retrieval for a cached static resource does not cache a copy on all cloudflare servers. In fact, I believe that cloudflare caches ray-wide in its caching implementation. It seems that the "1 second" TTFB is probably Cloudflare retrieving from your origin server and caching the result because it hasn't cached it for that ray yet.

Regardless of the above, it seems that the "1 second" TTFB is probably Cloudflare retrieving from your origin server and caching the result. To confirm this you can look at the response and there will be a CF-Cache-Status header that indicates HIT or MISS.  You will probably see that it is always MISS for the 1 second+ requests. You should also see another header called CF-Ray that looks something like 5abb86fb2d6c9bc1-SJC where the SJC is the data center code.  You should verify that this is a datacenter that is located geographically close to you to make sure that your DNS is set up correctly to get a nearby cloudflare server per the site list here: https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/